# [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: getDocumentos is not defined" found in ---> <BarProgreso> <Root>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

voy empezando en vue y javascript con esto de la exportación e importación de módulos y componentes en vue, yo normalmente hacia con Vue.component y no había tenido problemas en mapear el state, las mutaciones y los actions ahora en esta nueva manera de implementar me gustaría saber como poder mapear estos tres elementos. Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho.

app.js

```
import barProgreso from '../components/barProgreso.js';
import store from './store.js';
const app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    store:store,
    components: {
        'bar-progreso'     : barProgreso,
    }
})
```

store module->store.js

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        documentos:[],
    },
    mutations:{
        setDocumentos(docs){
            this.state.documentos = docs;
        }
    },
    actions:{
        getDocumentos:async function({commit}){
            const data = await fetch('documentos.json');
            const documentos = await data.json();
            commit("setDocumentos", documentos)
        }
    }
})
```

Componente ../components/barProgreso.js'

```
export default{
    mounted(){        
    },
    data: function () {
        return {                         
            percentage: 50,
            percent:50
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...Vuex.mapState(['documentos'])
    },
    methods:{
        ...Vuex.mapMutations(['setDocumentos']),
        ...Vuex.mapActions(['getDocumentos'])
    },

    created() {
        getDocumentos();
    },

    template: `
    <div>
        <div class="container">
        <div>{{ percent }}%</div>
        <div class="loading-bar">
            <div class="percentage" :style="{'width' : percentage + '%'}"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
   </div>      `
}
```

Comment: podrias compartir ../components/barProgreso.js' ? parece que alli esta el problema

Comment: de hecho es el que dice componente, el app.js es el archivo que agrego al index.html, el store js lo importo al app.js al igual que el componente o ../components/barProgreso.js. Desde ese archivo trato de mandar a llamar en el created a getDocumentos que se supone que es un action del store. Lo siento voy empezando con esto

Comment: en 
created() {
        getDocumentos();
    },  cambialo por created() {
        ...getDocumentos();
    }, o created() {
        getDocumentos : getDocumentos();
    },

Comment: Te agradezco tu apoyo, intente eso, pero me seguia marcando error, trabajar con las cdn es complicado, debido que en mi entorno de desarrollo no tengo acceso la ssh y para instalar todo de manera global por eso uso cdn. 
Navegando por ahi  esto fue mi solucion, en el componente donde mapeo los actions, state y las mutations, puse esto hasta el principio del modulo: Vue.use(Vuex); y el action lo llame con el this.getDocumentos().

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso como estoy usando cdns, debido a que en mi entorno no puedo instalar los recursos de manera global, ya que no tengo acceso a la terminal para hacerlo.

Navegando por ahí encontré esto. Si deseas mapear actions, state y mutations en algun modulo que usas como componente, al principio del documento usas

```
Vue.use(Vuex);
```

Los **actions y mutations** los mandas a llamar con la palabra reservada **this** dentro del componente.

El componente barProgreso quedaria asi de la siguiente manera

```
Vue.use(Vuex);

export default{
    mounted(){        
    },
    data: function () {
        return {                         
            percentage: 50,
            percent:50
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...Vuex.mapState(['documentos'])
    },
    methods:{
        ...Vuex.mapMutations(['setDocumentos']),
        ...Vuex.mapActions(['getDocumentos'])
    },

    created() {
        this.getDocumentos();
    },

    template: `
    <div>
        <div class="container">
        <div>{{ percent }}%</div>
        <div class="loading-bar">
            <div class="percentage" :style="{'width' : percentage + '%'}"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
   </div>      `
}
```